# How to put "Is not empty" as a hash value?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash, which I am using for an SQL query

```
:profiles => {:gender => Female, :idea => ''}
```

The way it is setup now, it is looking for profiles with gender female and an empty idea. Meaning the string in the idea column is empty. How do I get this to be the exact opposite. I want to find rows where the idea column is not empty.

**NOTE: I am not looking for IS NOT NULL because the string is empty and NOT NOT_NULL.**

Comment: What you have is not a hash. It is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to express this within the hash itself but you can use one of the other styles of querying e.g.

```
Profile.where("gender = ? and idea != ''", gender)
```

or if you upgrade to Rails 4 you can use the `not` method to invert a condition. e.g.

```
Profile.where.not(idea: '')
```

and you can combine multiple `where` calls e.g.

```
Profile.where(gender: 'Female').where.not(idea: '')
```

Comment: The question is tagged ruby-on-rails-3. Isn't `not` functionality that was added in rails-4?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for !string.empty?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with a hash.

You could however:

```
where('gender != ? OR gender IS NOT ?', '', nil)
```

Comment: I want the IDEA column to be not empty.